# What can I do to scrape 10000 pages without appearing captchas?

Tags: python, web-scraping, captcha, analysis, collect

Hi there i've been trying to collect all the information in 10,000 pages of this page for a school project, I thought everything was fine until on page 4 I got a mistake. I check the page manually and I find that the page now asks me for a captcha.

What can I do to avoid it? Maybe set a timer between the searchs?

Here it is my code.

```
import bs4, requests, csv

g_page = requests.get("http://www.usbizs.com/NY/New_York.html")
m_page = bs4.BeautifulSoup(g_page.text, "lxml")

get_Pnum = m_page.select('div[class="pageNav"]')
MAX_PAGE = int(get_Pnum[0].text[9:16])

print("Recolectando información de la página 1 de {}.".format(MAX_PAGE))
contador = 0
information_list = []
for k in range(1, MAX_PAGE):

    c_items = m_page.select('div[itemtype="http://schema.org/Corporation"] a')
    c_links = []
    i = 0

    for link in c_items:

        c_links.append(link.get("href"))
        i+=1

    for j in range(len(c_links)):
        temp = []
        s_page = requests.get(c_links[j])
        i_page = bs4.BeautifulSoup(s_page.text, "lxml")
        print("Ingresando a: {}".format(c_links[j]))
        info_t = i_page.select('div[class="infolist"]')

        info_1 = info_t[0].text
        info_2 = info_t[1].text
        temp = [info_1,info_2]
        information_list.append(temp)
        contador+=1

    with open ("list_information.cv", "w") as file:
        writer=csv.writer(file)
        for row in information_list:
            writer.writerow(row)

    print("Información de {} clientes recolectada y guardada correctamente.".format(j+1))    
    g_page = requests.get("http://www.usbizs.com/NY/New_York-{}.html".format(k+1))
    m_page = bs4.BeautifulSoup(g_page.text, "lxml")
    print("Recolectando información de la página {} de {}.".format(k+1,MAX_PAGE))

print("Programa finalizado. Información recolectada de {} clientes.".format(contador))
```

Comment: captchas are there by the devs, to stop spamming requests from humans or bots. They are there to discourage scraping. Maybe find a site that doesn't mind if you scrape from them. There are other ways to get around captchas, none full proof :\

Comment: You can do nothing unless you feel like embarking on a pretty difficult route with captcha parsing, OCR and stuff like that.

Comment: Talk to the people whose site you're scraping. Ideally, they'll give you a data dump or an approved API. It's also possible they'll give you a cease-and-desist letter, but they'd have done that if the level of scraping rose to their attention too. Academic use will often get a low-cost license, if you agree to restrictions on usage (or to offer an interest in any licensable development that comes out of the project).

Comment: @MooingRawr, incidentally, it's "foolproof", ie. proof against fools.

Comment: ...incidentally, if the site is itself populated with public-record information (as smells like might be the case here), you might consider going direct to the source instead of scraping someone who's presenting that information to the public.

Comment: @ForceBru, I did something similar to what you mention but on another page (differentiation between cats and dogs basically) but I ended up banned from the site. It's not that I care, but I'd rather not have to solve them.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks. edited: can't edited it anymore :\ oh well